# How public shopify app will appear to store visitors

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I successfully created a test shopify app, I calling Shopify API and retrieve the product list.

I installed the app on development store. Now the app appears in admin panel just for admins in apps tab and they can search and retrieve store products based on filtration criteria.

My questions:

> How public visitors or registered customers can access my app ?

Also

> How to override the shopify search engine without installing apps from
>   store, I need to create my own app but how to override something
>   in core like the search engine ?

I hope that I asking about something logical if not please let me know the correct scenario I'm new in shopify apps development.

Answer (score 0):

If your App presents data to the front-end, ie) to customers of the Shopify store, your best bet is to hook up an App Proxy in the App. That lets the theme Liquid code callback to your App asking for specific data. You can then provide JSON or Liquid as two examples.

As for search, just override the Liquid you see in search.liquid to provide your own search data. You can either filter what Shopify provides, or again, do a callback to your App for data and present that.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions really its very helpful, I taken a look on app proxy https://help.shopify.com/en/api/embedded-apps/app-extensions/online-store/application-proxies but what is the proxy url ? in my case my application contains shopify controller with auth and install actions, should i create a new action for proxy or what ?